# Prove that every module $M$ is epic image of a projective module.

Tags: homological-algebra

*My Proof:* We knew that every module $M$ is epic image of a free module and a free module is a projective module, hence every module $M$ is epic image of a projective module.

Is that true?! If false, please give me a hint.

Comment: Your proof is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This CW answer intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As already noted in the comments, your proof is right.